# Positions UI Elements In IOS Relatively like HTML

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

What is the best way to arrange elements on top of each other relatively where I can remove one and all the other elements move up.  Below is a screenshot of elements built dynamically and place at a specific x and y value, but can I just use IB and add my elements in a relative way and when I want to hide one everything moves up.  Also if I wanted to do it dynamically and add UI elements stacked on each other.  My issues below is the state/city sometimes doesnt exist and I want the games button to move up when its hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add all these objects in a mutable array. Set the object by using a for loop. after each loop execution increment the object frame's y value with a specific value. If one object need not be displayed, then remove it from the array and execute the for loop

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:label1,label2,label3,label4];
int y = 50;
for(int i = 0; i<[array count];i++)
{

    [array objectAtIndex:i].frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
    [self.view addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    y = y+50;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever decide to go with Auto Layout, here's one solution.

The key to my approach is that most of the constraints I created in IB are placeholder constraints; that is, they are removed automatically by the system at runtime. This way, I can layout the subviews dynamically at runtime in code.

The only constraints created in IB that are not placeholders are the following:

1. width constraint for game button
2. the constraint that horizontally centers the game button in its superview

The game button is never removed at runtime, so it's okay to keep these constraints in place at runtime.

If a label's text is nil, then it's removed from the view hierarchy in viewDidLoad.

[image]

[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gamesButton;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewsStack;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // for testing...
    //self.label1.text = nil;
    //self.label2.text = nil;
    self.label3.text = nil;

    // build stack of views and remove labels with no text
    self.viewsStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (UILabel *label in @[self.label1, self.label2, self.label3]) {

        if (label.text != nil) {
            [self.viewsStack addObject:label];
        } else {
            [label removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    [self.viewsStack addObject:self.gamesButton];

    [self configureConstraintsForViewsStack:self.viewsStack];
}

#define VERTICAL_SPACER 15

- (void)configureConstraintsForViewsStack:(NSArray *)views
{
    NSString *format = @"V:[topLayoutGuide]";
    NSMutableDictionary *viewsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [viewsDictionary setObject:self.topLayoutGuide forKey:@"topLayoutGuide"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
        format = [format stringByAppendingFormat:@"-spacer-[view%d]", i];
        [viewsDictionary setObject:views[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"view%d", i]];
    }

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:@{@"spacer": @(VERTICAL_SPACER)} views:viewsDictionary]];
}
```